# matching two mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

This is a beginner php/mysql question, I've messed around for hours with various loops but I haven't been able to reach the goal. I have two tables in the db. One that contains books and one that contain the stock info for the books. Like this:

```
id  title
1   A book
2   Another book
3   A third book
```

and for the stock (book_stock)

```
id  book_id   warehouse_id   qty
1   1         1              12
2   1         2              45
3   2         3              22
4   3         1              78
5   1         3              15
```

I want to read the tables, match the id from book table with book_id from stock table and then output a summary in a html table, showing book titles and how many of each book exist in the different warehouses. What I've tried so far involves looping mysql requests, something that seems to crash since it outputs no results. I have a feeling the solutions is simple and involves arrays but my skills are lacking...

Here is my non-working code. The function works fine for 1, 2 and even 20 results entered manually, but only outputs blank table cells when looped.

```
//function to get stock based on book id number
function get_stock($book_row_number)
{
    //get BOOK from db
    $book_query="SELECT * FROM book";
    $book_result=mysql_query($book_query);

    //determine book info
    $book_id=mysql_result($book_result,$book_row_number,"id");
    $book_title=mysql_result($book_result,$book_row_number,"title");

    //get LONDON stock for this book from db
    $stock_query="SELECT qty FROM book_stock WHERE book_id='$book_id' AND warehouse_id='1'";
    $stock_result=mysql_query($stock_query);
    $stock_london=mysql_result($stock_result,0,"qty");

    //get USA stock for this book from db
    $stock_query="SELECT qty FROM book_stock WHERE book_id='$book_id' AND warehouse_id='2'";
    $stock_result=mysql_query($stock_query);
    $stock_usa=mysql_result($stock_result,0,"qty");

    //get GERMANY stock for this book from db
    $stock_query="SELECT qty FROM book_stock WHERE book_id='$book_id' AND warehouse_id='4'";
    $stock_result=mysql_query($stock_query);
    $stock_germany=mysql_result($stock_result,0,"qty");

    echo "<tr><td>$book_title</td><td>$stock_london</td><td>$stock_usa</td><td>$stock_germany</td></tr>\n";
}

//find number of rows in book list
$all_query="SELECT * FROM book";
$all_result=mysql_query($all_query);
$all_rows=mysql_numrows($all_result);

// run the function on all the rows
$i=0;
while ($i < $all_rows) {
    get_stock('$all_rows');
    $i++;
}
```

EDIT: And the code as it is now

```
<?php

//set up connection
$user="username";
$password="paswd";
$database="database";
mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

//query
$book_query="SELECT
book_id,
title,
SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 1 THEN book_stock.qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse1,
SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 2 THEN book_stock.qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse2,
SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 3 THEN book_stock.qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse3,
SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 4 THEN book_stock.qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse4
FROM
book_stock
JOIN book ON book.id = book_stock.book_id
GROUP BY book_id, title";

//loop
$result = mysql_query($book_query);
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['title']) . "</td><td>{$row['warehouse1']}</td><td>{$row['warehouse2']}</td><td>{$row['warehouse3']}</td><td>{$row['warehouse4']}</td></tr>";
  }
}
else echo mysql_error();



//close database
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single query, if you build it as a pivot table. The idea is that the `SUM()` aggregates add together the value of `qty` for the matching `warehouse_id`, or 0 when it doesn't match for each row, collapsing all the warehouses into a single row.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 1 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 2 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 3 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 4 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse4
FROM
  book_stock
WHERE book_id = $book_id
```

For `book_id = 1`, this produces a result like:

```
warehouse1 warehouse2 warehouse3 warehouse4
       12        45          15          0
```

To get it for all books in rows, add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  book_id,
  title,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 1 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 2 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 3 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN warehouse_id = 4 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS warehouse4
FROM
  book_stock
  JOIN book ON book.id = book_stock.book_id
GROUP BY book_id, title
```

Output from PHP is then a trivial `while` loop:

```
// Assuming you already opened your <table>
$result = mysql_query($the_big_query_above);
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['title']) . "</td><td>{$row['warehouse1']}</td><td>{$row['warehouse2']}</td><td>{$row['warehouse3']}</td><td>{$row['warehouse4']}</td></tr>";
  }
}
else echo mysql_error();

// Then don't forget to close your </table>
```

Comment: @jimmy using the second query, you can run it for all books at once then print it in the PHP loop I just added..  The first query at the top is run per book.

Comment: I don't think I'm writing the query correctly. How do I reach the $row variable?

Comment: It prints "Column 'qty' in field list is ambiguous".

Comment: @jimmy Do you have `qty` in the `books` table as well as the `book_stock` table? If so, replace all 4 of the `THEN qty` with `THEN book_stock.qty` That's the only way I can see you getting an ambiguous column error.

Comment: Turns out there was a qty in that table as well. I changed as you suggested, the error is gone but there is no output. Thank you for staying with me!

Comment: @jimmy Execute the query alone with a client like phpmyadmin and verify it first. You should see as many rows output as you have books in the `books` table.

Comment: Doing the query in phpmyadmin produced beautiful results, just what i was looking for. Strange that it won't output still.
My connection is like this:
`$user="username";
$password="longdifficult";
$database="bookshop";
mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");`

Comment: Is `localhost` really not quoted?  It should be, though that will throw a notice rather than an error.  Post your current PHP. Does it look just like mine that I posted?

Comment: @jimmy I see you posted your code. You don't have opening and closing `<table></table>` so your table rows and cells probably won't render. View your page source - I bet you will see the HTML there.

Comment: while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($row) ) should be while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ), or you won't get any output. Depending on your settings, you may get a PHP notice $row undefined.

Comment: @jimmy, Calle spotted my error in the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` call.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael! With Calle's correction it is working now. I really need to study the mysql request functions more...

Comment: @jimmy I recommend investing your time in learning MySQLi or PDO prepared statements rather than in the `mysql_*()` functions, as they are difficult to use securely and are planned for deprecation. They're basically a dead end. I prefer [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if only because it is a little less verbose to code in than [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).